# Как с помощью Thymleaf + Spring можно сделать редирект на нужную область страницы

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Есть метод PostMapping который с сохраняет новый комментарий под постом. Так как комментариев может быть много, я хочу сделать редирект на нужную область с добавленным комментарием. Пример на html - http://htmlbook.ru/content/ssylki-vnutri-stranitsy .

Controller -

```
@PostMapping("{name}")
public String addComment(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestParam String text,
        @PathVariable("name") String name) {
    Post movie = postService.getPostById(Long.valueOf(name.replaceAll("-.*$", "")));
    Comment comment = new Comment(text, LocalDateTime.now(), user, post);
    commentService.saveComment(comment);
    return "redirect:" + name + "#comment";
}
```

thymleaf -

```
<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()" id="disauthorize">
 <a th:href="@{/login}">Зарегестрируйтесь</a> для возможности оставлять комментарий</div>
 <a name="#comment"></a>
 <div class="row" th:each="comment : ${post.getComments()}">
  ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот небольшой пример как это можно реализовать.

Контроллер:

```
package com.somepackage;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

@Controller
public class CommentController {

    @GetMapping("/comments/new")
    public String newComment(
            Model model) {
        CommentDTO comment = new CommentDTO();
        comment.setId(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()));

        model.addAttribute("comment", comment);

        return "comment/new";
    }

    @PostMapping("/comments/save")
    public String saveComment(
            CommentDTO comment,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("newComment", comment);

        return "redirect:/comments#" + comment.getId();
    }

    @GetMapping("/comments")
    public String showComments(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Model model) {
        List<CommentDTO> comments = new ArrayList<>();

        CommentDTO comment1 = new CommentDTO();
        comment1.setId(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()));
        comment1.setText("Text #" + comment1.getId());
        comments.add(comment1);

        CommentDTO comment2 = new CommentDTO();
        comment2.setId(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong()));
        comment2.setText("Text #" + comment2.getId());
        comments.add(comment2);

        Map<String, ?> inputFlashMap =
                RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
        if (inputFlashMap != null) {
            CommentDTO newBlog = (CommentDTO) inputFlashMap.get("newComment");
            comments.add(newBlog);
        }

        model.addAttribute("comments", comments);
        return "comment/list";
    }

}
```

Представление `list.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Comments</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div th:each="comment : ${comments}">
        <a th:name="${comment.id}" th:text="${comment.id}" th:href="@{'/comments/'+${comment.id}}"></a>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Представление `new.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New comment</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/comments/save}" th:object="${comment}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{text}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" id="id">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
```